# getting the matching words from two string arrays and changing words that are off by one letter

Tags: java, arrays, string, string-matching

I have one String[] that is `userInput` and another String[] `fileInput` that is input read from a file. I'm trying to get the words inside `userInput` that match the ones from the file input. NOTE: all words are 3 letters only.
The tricky part is that I have to change the `userInput` words that are off by only one letter to the correct word inside `fileInput`.
for example, my string array `fileInput` contains: [cat, dog, run, man, jaw, max] so if one of the indexes in `userInput`contains the word **bat** I have to change it to **cat**. 
Any help is appreciated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length; ++i) {
        if (Arrays.toString(fileInput).contains(userInput[i])) {
            match += userInput[i] + " ";
            userInput[i] = null;
        }


    }
    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length; ++i) {
        if (userInput[i] != null){

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  This could be done with traditional methods, or by using streams

Comment: @phflack yes I have tried for loops. but it didn't work. I don't understand why I'm getting a downvote I'm just asking a question. Can you please elaborate further

Comment: Post your code (downvote wasn't me)

Comment: @phflack I have tried much stuff but I cant seem to be able to figure it out. this is my code as of right now but it needs some editing

Comment: The user/file input works, and you're only having issues with finding similar words, right?

Comment: @phflack well finding the similar words is not completely the problem, its that I have to find the matching words as well as changing the ones that are off by one letter only I don't know how I can do that, I tried char arrays and a bunch of other ways but I wasn't able to implement them in a way that works for this specific task.

Comment: @phflack do you know how I can go about this problem, I researched online and a lot of people are using patterns but we have yet to learn these so I'm not sure what to do at this point

Comment: @phflack I updated my code so it's more clear. please let me know if you have any ideas, basically I just need to compare every char value for the words are not **null** to check if only one character is different from the words that are in `fileInput`

Comment: @phflack i really need help man please let me know if you have thoughts

Comment: Hang on, on a bus right now

Comment: Got to a computer to format it, the app crashed while I was typing it up

Answer (score 0):

Try this i created some fake data to test

```
String[] userInput = {"cat", "dog", "run", "man"};

String[] fileInput = {"bat", "mat", "zzz", "aaa"};

ArrayList<String> sameInput = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < fileInput.length; j++) {
        char[] userChars = userInput[i].toCharArray();
        char[] fileChars = fileInput[j].toCharArray();

        boolean[] booleans = new boolean[userChars.length];


        for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
            if (fileChars[x] == userChars[x])
                booleans[x] = true;
            else
                booleans[x] = false;

        int count = 0;
        for (boolean bool : booleans)
            if (bool)
                count++;

        if (count >= 2)
            sameInput.add(userInput[i]);
    }
}

for (String o : sameInput) System.out.println(o);
```

There is many flaws with this because there are a lot of 3 letter words that have  letters in common but good luck

Comment: where are the matching words added to? im trying to add the matching words to a different string.

Comment: this code doesnt seem to change anything inside the String arrays at all? can you please explain to me further

Comment: `if(a == b) bool = true; else bool = false;` can be simplified with `bool = a == b;`.  It may also be easier to just sum directly instead of using to `booleans` array

Comment: @kingabidalX took me a bit to spot as well, but it changes `mat` to `cat` in the `fileInput` array

Comment: @kingabidalX it changes it in the original array that I named fileInput also phflack feel free to edit the answer if you can make it more efficient

Comment: @Matt hello, sorry I wasn't home, I'm just supposed to add the matching words to a separate string. Do you know how I can make this code do that instead?

Comment: @kingabidalX like that?

Answer (score 0):

Inputs:

- Array of user inputs (Strings of length 3)
- Array of file inputs, the dictionary to check against (Strings of length 3)

Outputs:

- Array of checked words (can just modify user inputs instead)

As a function:

```
String[] verify(String[] input, String[] dict)
{
    String[] output = new String[input.length];
    System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, input.length);
    loop: for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
        for(String s : dict)
            if((s.charAt(0) == output[i].charAt(0) ? 1 : 0) + (s.charAt(1) == output[i].charAt(1) ? 1 : 0) + (s.charAt(2) == output[i].charAt(2) ? 1 : 0) == 2)
            {
                output[i] = s;
                continue loop;
            }
    return output;
}
```

I'm sure there's a better way to check if 3 digits are the same, the if statement just sums how many are equal

To prioritize equal values (so if "cat" and "mat" are entries in the dictionary, user input "cat" won't be changed to "mat"):

```
String[] verify(String[] input, String[] dict)
{
    String[] output = new String[input.length];
    System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, input.length);
    loop: for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
    {
        for(String s : dict)
            if(s.charAt(0) == output[i].charAt(0) && s.charAt(1) == output[i].charAt(1) && s.charAt(2) == output[i].charAt(2))
                continue loop;

        for(String s : dict)
            if((s.charAt(0) == output[i].charAt(0) ? 1 : 0) + (s.charAt(1) == output[i].charAt(1) ? 1 : 0) + (s.charAt(2) == output[i].charAt(2) ? 1 : 0) == 2)
            {
                output[i] = s;
                continue loop;
            }
    }

    return output;
}
```

---

To get distinct arrays of matched words, corrected words, and invalid words:

```
String[][] verify(String[] input, String[] dict)
{
    List<String> matched = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> corrected = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> missing = new ArrayList<String>();

    loop: for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        for(String s : dict)
            if(s.charAt(0) == input[i].charAt(0) && s.charAt(1) == input[i].charAt(1) && s.charAt(2) == input[i].charAt(2))
            {
                matched.add(input[i]);
                continue loop;
            }

        for(String s : dict)
            if((s.charAt(0) == input[i].charAt(0) ? 1 : 0) + (s.charAt(1) == input[i].charAt(1) ? 1 : 0) + (s.charAt(2) == input[i].charAt(2) ? 1 : 0) == 2)
            {
                corrected.add(s);
                continue loop;
            }
        missing.add(input[i]);
    }

    return new String[][]{matched.toArray(new String[0]), corrected.toArray(new String[0]), missing.toArray(new String[0])};
}
```

- output[0] - matched words
- output[1] - corrected words
- output[2] - missing words

Comment: this code seems to be working for the most part, but how do i make it not add the words that do not match at all? for example if i just entered 'aaa' it would still add it to my final String

Comment: @kingabidalX What is it that you actually want?  One array of exact matches and corrections?  An array of each?

Comment: i just want it to have a String that has all the matching words and the ones that are corrected by one letter. and to throw a **LengthException** (my own excpetion) if there is a word that is incorrect, and to rethrow the same **LengthException** if that same word has more than could not be corrected (two or more different letters) does that make sense?

Comment: @phflack-------